# Railsのeach文で作ったものの表示上限を決めたいです

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**やりたいこと**
自作アプリ内で，以下のeach文を使って投稿を表示しているのですが，仮にですが表示上限を10個までとしたいです．
その際に，古いものから消えていくような仕様にしたいです．

```
<% @notifications.each do |notification| %>
  <div class="notifications-index-item">
  <% case notification.action %>
  <% when "post" %>
    <%= link_to(notification.post.dear, "/posts/#{notification.post.id}") %> <br>
  <% when "reply" %>
    <%= link_to(notification.reply.dear, "/replies/#{notification.reply.id}") %> <br>
  <% else %>
    <p>まだ来ていません</p>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

今のままだと，おそらく無制限に投稿が表示されてしまうので，どなたかに教えていただきたいです．

**追記**

**notification.rb**

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord

  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(10) }
  belongs_to :post, optional: true
  belongs_to :reply, optional: true

  belongs_to :visitor, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'visitor_id', optional: true
  belongs_to :visited, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'visited_id', optional: true

end
```

**notifications_controller.rb**

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @notifications=current_user.passive_notifications
    #@notifications.where(checked: false).each do |notification|
      #notification.update_attribute(:checked, "true")
    #end
  end
end
```

**User.rb** made by devise

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
        :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable

  attribute :received_at, :datetime, default: -> { Time.now }

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :birthday, presence: true
  validates :received_at, presence: true


  #アクティブで自分からの通知パッシブは他人から
  has_many :active_notifications, class_name: "Notification", foreign_key: "visitor_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :passive_notifications, class_name: "Notification", foreign_key: "visited_id", dependent: :destroy
end
```

**参考にしたもの**
[【Rails】通知機能を誰でも実装できるように解説する【いいね、コメント、フォロー】](https://qiita.com/nekojoker/items/80448944ec9aaae48d0a)

Answer (score 3):

`@notifications` がナニモノかに依りますが:

- 配列の場合
  `@notifications.sort_by(&:ソートしたい日時項目).reverse.take(10).each do...`
  の様に並び換えた上で [`Array#take`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/Array.html#I_TAKE) を使えば良いと思います。
  並び換えは `sort_by {...}.reverse` ではなく `sort {|a, b| b.日時項目 <=> a.日時項目 }` としても良いでしょう。
  既に並び順が新しいものが先頭となるようになっていれば、take だけ追加すれば良いと思います。
- AcitveRecord モデルのクエリ結果の場合
  クエリに `order(ソートしたい日時属性: :desc).limit(10)` を追加すれば良いと思います。
  すでに order をつけているのであれば、limit だけ追加すれば良いと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．一応追記しましたが，おそらくヤマシタさんの言う後者だと思います．このnotification.rb内の "default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(10) }"　でいけますか？

Comment: +1: 加えて、この操作はビューではなくてコントローラーで行うと ActiveRecord を操作するコードがコントローラーに集まって責務の分離が分かりやすくなると思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます．この操作をビューではなく，コントローラで行った場合どういったようなコードになるのでしょうか？

Comment: まず default_scope は何かとハマりがちなので使わない方が良いと思います。
今後色々条件を追加するさい解除が難しく面倒になりがちです。

Comment: (Enterキーで確定されてしまうのに慣れない…)
ビューと同様に現在のコントーラがどのようなコードになっているか提示された方が話をしやすいと思います。

Comment: 調べてみたらdefault_scopeがあまり良い評判でないのはわかりました（なぜかはまだわかってませんが）notificationコントローラを追記しました．

Comment: 「コントローラで行った場合どういったようなコードになるなるのでしょうか？」について、まず答えを書いてしまうと次の様になります。

`@notifications = current_user.passive_notifications.order(created_at: :desc).limit(10)`

※ notification.rb から default_scope を消しておく前提。
scope を使えばもう少しすっきりします。 
Qiita の [Railsでよく利用する、Scopeの使い方。](https://qiita.com/ngron/items/14a39ce62c9d30bf3ac3) あたりが参考になると思います。

Comment: で、ちょっと興味本位で聞いてみたいのですが、「コントローラで設定している `@notifications` と ビューで参照している `@notifications` は同じもの」「最初に `@notifications` に order と limit を使えば良いと回答」「`@notifications` は current_user.passive_notifications の返却値」であることから、直前のコメントの内容は半ば自明のものです。どのあたりでつまづいていたのか、後学のため教えていただけないしょうか?

Comment: 丁寧な説明ありがとうございます．まず.order(created_at: :desc).limit(10)をpassive_notificationsにそのままつければいいという風に理解できませんでした．というのも，質問文にあるようにビューの中のeach文内で10回分表示，という発想しかなかったため，ヤマシタさんに教えていただいてもらった「この操作はビューではなくてコントローラーで行うと ActiveRecord を操作するコードがコントローラーに集まって責務の分離が分かりやすくなると思います」という部分が，each文まで含めた処理をコントローラに書く，ということかなと思い，どうやって書くんだろうと思いました．@notificationsに格納する段階で，数を決めて入れる順番を決めたものを変数に格納する，それをあとはビューで書くだけ，という細かなステップの認識ができていなかったのだと思います．